# Load and compile an external .java file

Tags: java

What is the best way to load a `.java` file call the main method and execute the code. So for instance if I call `C:/Test.java` it should execute the code.

My code right now is the following:

```java
final JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
final DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<>();
final StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
final Iterable<<? extends JavaFileObject>compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(Arrays.asList("C:/test.java"));
final JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, null, null, compilationUnits);

final boolean success = task.call();

try {
    System.out.println("Compiled: " + success);
    fileManager.close();
} catch (final IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But it also generate a `.class` file in the folder which I don't want. Is this code good for java 14 or there is a better way?

Comment: Refer to [JEP 330](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330). You can pass the path of a java source code file to the `java` command. Is that relevant?

Comment: It's Java7, but perhaps you can still make use of it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173294/compile-code-fully-in-memory-with-javax-tools-javacompiler

Answer (score 1):

First you can simplify the code a bit. You use the [StandardJavaFileManager](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/tools/StandardJavaFileManager.html) and it imports the interface `Auto/Closeable`. So you can use the [try-with-resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739362/whats-the-purpose-of-try-with-resources-statements):

```java
final JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
final DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<>();

try (final StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null)) {
    final Iterable<<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(Arrays.asList("C:/test.java"));
    final JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, null, null, compilationUnits);

    final boolean success = task.call();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Second you need the `.class` file to execute your java program. There exists a nice [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733132/purpose-for-class-files-in-java/). If you want to execute your test file and you use the command line, you should use the following commands:

```sh
javac Test.java
java Test

// or a little bit shorter
java Test.java
```

If you want to know more about compilation, I can recommend this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757189/how-do-i-run-java-class-files) or this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56362575/10951752).

Answer (score 0):

By implementing `JavaFileObject` yourself and "patching" `JavaFileManager` you can keep the compiler in-memory, and then via exposing `defineClass()` of `ClassLoader` you can load the resulting byte array and launch `main()` via reflection.

Here is a condensed variant, it actually does what you asked for, loads source code from file (that's one line with `Files.readString()` anyway). However that's something what you can probably leave entirely to the patched `JavaFileManager`, just I focused on keeping even the source code in memory, that's why there is the commented `String src = "...";` block.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.lang.model.element.*;
import javax.tools.*;

public class SOCompileTestDense {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String name="Test";
//    String src="public class Test {\r\n" + 
//        "  public static void main(String[] args) {\r\n" + 
//        "    System.out.println(\"Hello \"+args[0]+\"!\");\r\n" + 
//        "  }\r\n" + 
//        "}";
    String src=Files.readString(Paths.get(name+".java"));
    System.out.println(src);
    List<JFO> sources=Arrays.asList(new JFO(name,src));
    Map<String,JFO> files=new HashMap<>();
    JavaCompiler jc=ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    JavaCompiler.CompilationTask ct=jc.getTask(null, new JFM(jc.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null),files), null, null, null, sources);
    System.out.println(ct.call());
    Class<?> clazz=new CL().defineClass(name, files.get(name).baos.toByteArray());
    clazz.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class).invoke(null, (Object)new String[] {"StackOverflow"});
  }
  
  static class JFO implements JavaFileObject {
    final String name;
    final String src;
    JFO(String name,String src){
      this.name=name;
      this.src=src;
    }

    public URI toUri() {
      try {
        return new URI(name);
      } catch(URISyntaxException use) {use.printStackTrace();};
      return null;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
    public OutputStream openOutputStream() throws IOException {
      baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      return baos;
    }

    public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) throws IOException {
      return src;
    }

    public Kind getKind() {
      return Kind.SOURCE;
    }

    public boolean isNameCompatible(String simpleName, Kind kind) {
      return name.equals(simpleName);
    }

    public InputStream openInputStream() throws IOException {return null;}
    public Reader openReader(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) throws IOException {return null;}
    public Writer openWriter() throws IOException {return null;}
    public long getLastModified() {return 0;}
    public boolean delete() {return false;}
    public NestingKind getNestingKind() {return null;}
    public Modifier getAccessLevel() {return null;}
  }
  
  static class JFM implements JavaFileManager {
    final JavaFileManager jfm;
    final Map<String, JFO> files;
    JFM(JavaFileManager jfm, Map<String, JFO> files){
      this.jfm=jfm;
      this.files=files;
    }

    public int isSupportedOption(String option) {
      return jfm.isSupportedOption(option);
    }

    public ClassLoader getClassLoader(Location location) {
      return jfm.getClassLoader(location);
    }

    public Iterable<JavaFileObject> list(Location location, String packageName, Set<JavaFileObject.Kind> kinds, boolean recurse) throws IOException {
      return jfm.list(location, packageName, kinds, recurse);
    }

    public String inferBinaryName(Location location, JavaFileObject file) {
      return jfm.inferBinaryName(location, file);
    }

    public boolean handleOption(String current, Iterator<String> remaining) {
      return jfm.handleOption(current, remaining);
    }

    public boolean hasLocation(Location location) {
      return jfm.hasLocation(location);
    }

    public JavaFileObject getJavaFileForInput(Location location, String className, JavaFileObject.Kind kind) throws IOException {
      return jfm.getJavaFileForInput(location, className, kind);
    }

    public JavaFileObject getJavaFileForOutput(Location location, String className, JavaFileObject.Kind kind, FileObject sibling) throws IOException {
      JFO jfo=new JFO(className,null);
      files.put(className, jfo);
      return jfo;
    }
    
      public String inferModuleName(Location location) throws IOException {
        return jfm.inferModuleName(location);
      }

      public Iterable<Set<Location>> listLocationsForModules(Location location) throws IOException {
        return jfm.listLocationsForModules(location);
      }
      
    public boolean isSameFile(FileObject a, FileObject b) {return false;}
    public FileObject getFileForInput(Location location, String packageName, String relativeName) throws IOException {return null;}
    public FileObject getFileForOutput(Location location, String packageName, String relativeName, FileObject sibling) throws IOException {return null;}
    public void flush() throws IOException {}
    public void close() throws IOException {}
  }
  
  static class CL extends ClassLoader {
    public Class<?> defineClass(String name,byte array[]) {
      return defineClass(name, array, 0, array.length);
    }
  }
}
```

And this is a tidy, short version, its output looks as follows:

> ```
> public class Test {
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>     System.out.println("Hello "+args[0]+"!");
>   }
> }
> true
> Hello StackOverflow!
> ```

A much longer variant with verbose output is available on Ideone, https://ideone.com/DAXIlH, and if you download that one and remove the `//` in front of various `System.out.println();` calls, it will display a lot more stuff, which were simply too much for Ideone.
Practically what I did was implementing all methods as `throw new Error();` (see code on Ideone), and gradually filled them out with something meaningful whenever they got actually called. Actually it was pretty straigtforward, the only gotcha I ran into was a couple `default` methods of the `JavaFileManager` interface. As eclipse did not provide a stub implementation of those, it was a bit of surprise when code died without touching my `throw new Error();` lines.